# web.py doesn't delete stop between requests

Tags: python, web.py, pythonanywhere

Took me a very long time to figure out what the problem was, and now I don't know how to solve it.

I'm using pythonanywhere to run my web.py server

So here's the problem. The web.py instance does not stop running between server requests.
Let me demonstrate what heppens because of that.

I have a list that gets populated in a loop with **list.append(number)**
So during the first request to the server the script runs fine.
**list = (1, 2, 3)**

However, since the web.py instance does not cease, on the second request to the server **list** ends up being **(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)** and my script doesn't work.

How do I know web.py doesn't stop running between requests? When I deleted every namespace at the end of the scripts life, the second request to the server returned an error saying that '**web** was not defined'

> class web_serve:

```
def GET(self):

    data_obj = volumePit_google()
    plotter = volumePit_plot()

    data_obj.download('SPY', 2)
    data_obj.organize()

    price, volume = zip(*data_obj.data_final)
    plot_edges = data_obj.plotter_edges
    e_test = data_obj.data_ticks

    plotter.maxmin(price)
    data_obj.plotter_ticks()

    for i, tick in enumerate(data_obj.data_ticks[1:]):
        edges = [data_obj.data_ticks[i], tick]
        volume_edges = [plot_edges[i], plot_edges[i+1]]

        day_data = data_obj.data_final[edges[0]:edges[1]]
        price, volume = zip(*day_data)

        plotter.dividers(volume_edges)

        price_position = data_obj.price_action(price, [volume_edges[0], volume_edges[1]])
        plotter.subplot.plot(price_position, price, color='g', ls='-', lw='1')

        histogram = data_obj.histogram(day_data, 0)
        plotter.volume_profile(histogram, volume_edges)

    plotter.ticks([data_obj.plotter_edges, data_obj.dates, data_obj.plotter_tick_pos])

    data_stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
    plt.savefig(data_stream, bbox_inches='tight')
    data_stream.seek(0)
    return_png = base64.b64encode(data_stream.read())
    data_stream.close()

    return return_png
```

The variables that need clearing are within **data_obj**

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but both of the below classes are defined in the same file
data_obj = volumePit_google()
plotter = volumePit_plot()

```
class volumePit_google:
data = []
data_final = []

day_volume = []
data_ticks = [] #list contains indexes of the data_final separating days
dates = []

plotter_tick_pos = []
plotter_edges = [0]

def download(self, ticker, period):
```

Comment: Could you please show some code sample? It's not clear where is your variabe located, so I don't know what to suggest

Comment: AFAIK web.py creates a new request object everytime, i.e. instance variables of `web_serve` should not survive between requests. But .. what does `volumePit_google()` return? A new object everytime or a cached/global one?

Comment: It's a class defined in the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine why you would want the server to stop between requests. That would be extraordinarily inefficient.

You should simply avoid keeping global/module-level objects.

**Edited** Now you have finally posted the code to the `volumePit_google` class, we can see what the problem is. Anything defined at *class* level in Python is a class variable, shared between all members of the class. What you need instead is *instance* variables, which are defined each time the class is instantiated:

```
class volumePit_google(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.data_final = []

        self.day_volume = []
        self.data_ticks = [] #list contains indexes of the data_final separating days
        self.dates = []

        self.plotter_tick_pos = []
        self.plotter_edges = [0]
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python. How would I do that? del doesn't seem to work

Comment: How should we know? You've carefully avoided showing any code. But I can't see how `del` would help: you should just avoid defining anything at module level.

Comment: Sorry I don't completely understand what you mean by not defining anything at module level

Comment: You can also use this persistence to cache the output of functions as well... Just a thought.